# Add minimal support or breaking layer in multi part

Tags: slicing, support-structures, support-material

I am new to 3D printing, so this is probably a simple one.
I am using Freecad to design and Bambu slicer for printing. The object (simple cable clip) basically consists of vertical walls with no relevant overhangs. However, for printing, I have stacked seven of them in a vertical tower separating all seven objects by a small gap.

[image: Bambu slicer's preview of seven cable clips stacked on top of each other]

When I slice this with supports enabled, I get a preview that somewhat looks like Devil's Tower. I tried to draw the support manually and even blocked support at the walls which allows me to draw exactly what I want, but this doesn't change anything. The slicer still throws material at it like crazy.

What I ideally want is a single vertical support/breaking layer separating the parts. I know, I could model this breaking layer in Freecad, but the curved nature of the upper side makes sketching and modeling this quite difficult.

So my question is, is there an easy way to do this in a slicer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most easy solution is to edit the G-code file. In the G-code file you can see when the next stacked item starts to be printed. If there is no gap between the objects, the objects fuse together. If you insert G-code to raise the Z height by 0.1 - 0.2 mm and redefine the new Z to the old value prior to move you have created a weak/break layer similar to a support roof with a gap to the printed part.

So after the last layer of an object you insert:

```
// E.g. last Z is 15 mm, layer height is 0.2 mm
G1 Z15.15 // Raise Z height by 0.15 mm
G92 Z15   // Define this the Z you left
// Continue printing next object
```

Comment: Modifying this g-code file seems to be a powerfull option. I guess I first have to get some experience with it before modifying this thing. The g-code file for this project has more than a 100 thousand lines and I dont want to ruin the printer just yet. So what I did was, to add some support in the cad only at the bottom plate and then let the printer do its thing. The fact that there was a gap was enought to reduce layer adhesion between parts, so I could easily breake them apart.

Comment: @lmielke I usually write a python script for custom editing. You can also use scripts in the slicer itself. Your comment also is a solution, feel free to make this an answer!